# Is it possible to improve focus with the Samsung Galaxy S?

Tags: focus, android

Samsung Galaxy S video and photo quality is pretty good but only when fully focused. The focus is getting lost very easly and it become blurred. Are there any ways to increase focus quality and speed?

Comment: far more likely you're incapable of holding the phone steady enough to prevent blurring from shake (I refuse to call cellphones cameras).

Comment: @jwenting So... instead of a camera, it's the light-recording feature of a multi-function digital device? :)

Comment: no, it's a POS :)

Comment: actually i can hold but the objects can't stand :D

Answer (score 1):

I think you've run up against the limitation of the fact that its a multi function device that *also* includes a camera.

The camera focuses by contrast, so pointing at a particularly 'contrasty' portion of your subject may help.  Additionally, in lower light an additional light, like a flashlight, may help (some users report that using a laser to aid focus works well).

As far as modifying the camera or additional software for the device to focus better, its currently unlikely.